# "Console log" options doesn't appear in system log queries for Mac 10.7 console.app

Tags: mac, osx-lion, logging, console.app

In Mac OS 10.6, the Console.app had an option to show the "Console Log" which included what looks like the stdout/stderr message of running applications not explicitly sent to syslog. The option showed up as the second option in the system log queries/database queries list on the Log List.

In 10.7, the only option is "All Messages" and there does not appear to be a way to view the "console log" as it was in 10.6. Is there a way to turn this on in 10.7? Does the Mac no longer provide a way to see the stdout/stderr messages for running applications (those run as .app and not from terminal)?

Below are two images, one from the 10.6 console app that has the ability to see these messages and another from 10.7 that does not.

Note: I tried to post images of the two consoles but I'm a first time poster, so it wouldn't let me, see: [10.6 console.app](http://i41.tinypic.com/98bxbt.png) and [10.7 console.app](http://i44.tinypic.com/16hpzcm.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

on the Console app go to the menu "File" -> "New System Log Query" — (alt-cmd-N shortcut) and add a condition akin to:

[Facility] [is equal to] com.apple.console

I'm not sure if this what you're after, but this should be the same as executing "syslog -C" in the terminal, but it's more useful to have this info in the console.